# customizing TwentyEleven comments template

Tags: comment-form, comments, comments-template

Typically I don't utilize comments on my sites, however I'm using the comments functionality as a sort of live-feed testimonials page. To do this, I've borrowed `comments.php` and the comments portion of `functions.php` from the TwentyEleven theme. 
What I'm currently struggling with is how the comments/form are displaying on [the site](http://zoparealty.com/share/)
Ideally, I'd like the form to be on the left (inside `.content-left`) and the list of comments to be on the right (inside `.content-right`). Currently, the list of comments is both above the form in `.content-left` and where I'd like it to be in `.content-right`. How do I remove it from the left?

share.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Share
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<h1>We're All Ears.</h1>
<div class="content-left">

    <?php comments_template(); ?> 

</div><!-- end content-left -->
<div class="content-right">

    <?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyeleven_comment' )); ?></ul>

</div><!-- end content-right -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

comments.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments.
 *
 * The area of the page that contains both current comments
 * and the comment form. The actual display of comments is
 * handled by a callback to twentyeleven_comment() which is
 * located in the functions.php file.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
?>
    <div id="comments">
    <?php if ( post_password_required() ) : ?>
        <p class="nopassword"><?php _e( 'This post is password protected. Enter the password to view any comments.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
    </div><!-- #comments -->
    <?php
            /* Stop the rest of comments.php from being processed,
             * but don't kill the script entirely -- we still have
             * to fully load the template.
             */
            return;
        endif;
    ?>

    <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-above">
            <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav>
        <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php
                /* Loop through and list the comments. Tell wp_list_comments()
                 * to use twentyeleven_comment() to format the comments.
                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then you can
                 * define twentyeleven_comment() and that will be used instead.
                 * See twentyeleven_comment() in twentyeleven/functions.php for more.
                 */
                wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyeleven_comment' ) );
            ?>
        </ol>

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-below">
            <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav>
        <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

    <?php
        /* If there are no comments and comments are closed, let's leave a little note, shall we?
         * But we don't want the note on pages or post types that do not support comments.
         */
        elseif ( ! comments_open() && ! is_page() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) :
    ?>
        <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php comment_form(); ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```

functions.php

```
<?php 

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyeleven_comment' ) ) :
/**
 * Template for comments and pingbacks.
 *
 * To override this walker in a child theme without modifying the comments template
 * simply create your own twentyeleven_comment(), and that function will be used instead.
 *
 * Used as a callback by wp_list_comments() for displaying the comments.
 *
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */
function twentyeleven_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
        case 'pingback' :
        case 'trackback' :
    ?>
    <li class="post pingback">
        <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'twentyeleven' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?><?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?></p>
    <?php
            break;
        default :
    ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <article id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment">
            <footer class="comment-meta">
                <div class="comment-author vcard">
                    <?php
                        $avatar_size = 68;
                        if ( '0' != $comment->comment_parent )
                            $avatar_size = 39;

                        echo get_avatar( $comment, $avatar_size );

                        /* translators: 1: comment author, 2: date and time */
                        printf( __( '%1$s on %2$s <span class="says">said:</span>', 'twentyeleven' ),
                            sprintf( '<span class="fn">%s</span>', get_comment_author_link() ),
                            sprintf( '<a href="%1$s"><time pubdate datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a>',
                                esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
                                get_comment_time( 'c' ),
                                /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                                sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentyeleven' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() )
                            )
                        );
                    ?>

                    <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div><!-- .comment-author .vcard -->

                <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
                    <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></em>
                    <br />
                <?php endif; ?>

            </footer>

            <div class="comment-content"><?php comment_text(); ?></div>

            <div class="reply">
                <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => __( 'Reply <span>&darr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ), 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .reply -->
        </article><!-- #comment-## -->

    <?php
            break;
    endswitch;
}
endif; // ends check for twentyeleven_comment()

?>
```

Also, how can I go have the comment list display the user name as well as the info from the other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove it from the left. Delete the line containing `wp_list_comments` from comments.php

to display user name add `comment_author();`, for email use `comment_author_email();` & for url use `if(get_comment_author_url()) comment_author_url();`. `comment_text()` is already there.

These all go in the markup inside the function in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

In your example `share.php`,
You are loading the content query twice using in both cases `<?php comments_template(); ?>` and `wp_list_comments()` functions.

**wp_list_comments()** lists the comments on a particular post and it is used in comments.php. `comments.php` is mostly in your **theme folders** or if WordPress does not find it there would use the file found in the default theme folder. That is if you have not deleted the default theme that comes with WordPress.

**comments_template()** call the comment template. In your case, it would start with your theme followed by the default theme folder. In essence, this function would call **wp_list_comment** above.

To make comment form display at your left and the list comments content at your right, you need to modify the **comment.php file** you have. You use a **custom function through the callback** only if you would want to modify **structure of the comment template in terms of** `author name`, `how dates is showed`, `add more metadata to the comment`, maybe `voting on comment`.

Share.php

```
<?PHP
  /*
  Template Name: Share
  */
?>

 <?php get_header(); ?>

 <h1>We're All Ears.</h1>
 <div class="comment-content">
   <?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyeleven_comment' )); ?>
 </div>
```

comments.php
Put everything else in

```
 <div class="content-left">
  <?php comment_form(); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="content-right">
  //Everything gos here except `<?php comment_form(); ?>`
 </div>
```